# Application forced stopped. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to decode the logcat report. I am learning android and trying to implement intent, toast and custom toast in single app.

As far I know I did it correctly. I am attaching logcat trace.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bt4u.customtoast, PID: 24490
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.rr.neptune, iconPack:system, fontPkg:com.rr.neptune, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.rr.neptune, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.rr.neptune}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bt4u.customtoast/com.bt4u.customtoast.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.bt4u.customtoast.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Main activity

```
 b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Just clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT,0,0);
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
   }
```

Also tell me how to find the problem by using the log trace

Comment: The relevant part is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at com.bt4u.customtoast.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)`, meaning that in your class `MainActivity`, you're trying to set a `onClickListener` on a Button that is null

Comment: But I checked that's not true.

Comment: Post some relevant code from your MainActivity

Comment: Check your MainActivity, line 21

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to invert the order you're setting your buttons :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

This is quite important, since you first need to call `setContentView`, because that view is then used to call `view.findViewById`. If you try to do it before setting the view, you will not be able to get any of the view's elements.

EDIT : As for your second question, replace :

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Just clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT,0,0);
```

with :

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Just clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT,0,0).show();
```

Comment: Yes got it. I forget about it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any mistake in Toast part of main ? Since i am getting toast message while running this app

Comment: You were simply missing `toast.show();` at the end there

Answer (score 0):

You calling setContentView method wrong place

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 



        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Just clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT,0,0);
            } 
        }); 

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Is there any mistake in Toast part of main ? Since i am getting toast message while running this app.

Comment: try this one by one.... you comment and uncomment toast message.....   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Toast.makeText(this,"onCreate = ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this,"onCreate = ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }